# Error when yarn add and npm i

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

Good evening!
i'm trying to add some packages to my native react application but it's not working with either npm or yarn. i have uninstalled and reinstalled yarn but it has not changed anything
I use Windows 10.

for yarn :

```
yarn add react-navigation
yarn add v1.5.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find the binary git".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Boubacar\\Desktop\\blob\\essai\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
for npm :
npm i react-navigation
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Boubacar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-08T00_02_28_158Z-debug.log.
```

Help me please!

Comment: The error is quite clear, you need to install git

Answer (score 1):

The console log is plain and clear.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find the binary git".
```

Check/Install **Git** on your system.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows users, need to set environment path,  like

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```